# Could a kindly and knowledgeable editor with appropriate reputation please add romaji (or hiragana) to question 892?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

Could a kindly and knowledgeable editor with appropriate reputation please add romaji (or hiragana) to this question: [What is the difference between 特殊 and 特別?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/892/what-is-the-difference-between-and)

It seems to cover some points in which I am interested but my kanji knowledge is pre-infantile.

This may also serve as a prototype for questions of its type and how to tag them.

Comment: Not sure which browser you use... but http://www.polarcloud.com/rikaichan/ (firefox) or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jipdnfibhldikgcjhfnomkfpcebammhp (chrome) are pretty helpful for kanji you don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added rōmaji to the question and highest voted answer for you.

Maybe we should post such requests as comment on the respective question/answer rather than potentially flooding meta with these requests?

Comment: Thanks! I considered both methods and perhaps both would get noticed as quickly on a young SE site but sometimes a question or answer will already be flooded on a mature site.

Comment: @hippietrail Anyone can edit questions!  Users that don't have the edit privilege can still suggest edits that go into a queue to be approved.  (The queue was full so I just cleared it so that may have prevented the edit link from appearing, but fyi.)

Comment: @Rebecca: I know anyone can edit questions - I have done so a fair bit (-: But I didn't know the readings for those kanji and wanted to know if the question some topic I knew in spoken Japanese.